# Traverse header array from csv file for drop down list in P5.js

Tags: javascript, csv, for-loop, drop-down-menu, p5.js

I'm new to using CSV files and drop-down menus. Using P5.js I want to create one drop-down list of all the header names using a for loop but so far have only managed to make many seperate drop-down menus for each header name rather than having them all in a single drop-down menu as a list. It's probably something super simple but I can't see it:

```
      for(var i = 0; i < this.data.getColumnCount() ; i++)
          {
           // Create a select DOM element.
           this.select = createSelect();

           // Set select position.
          this.select.position(400, 50);
          var companySelect = this.data.columns;

          // Fill the options with all company names.
          this.select.option(companySelect[i]);
          };
```

This is what I see when it's executed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwVBI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Waht you actually do is to create a separat dropdown menu for each option.

First you have to create the dropdown menu by [`createSelect()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createSelect). Then you have to add the options to the menu by `this.select.option('kiwi')` in a loop:

```js
// Create a select DOM element.
this.select = createSelect();

// Set select position.
this.select.position(400, 50);

var companySelect = this.data.columns;
for(var i = 0; i < this.data.getColumnCount() ; i++) {

    // Fill the options with all company names.
    this.select.option(companySelect[i]);
};
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be something simple haha